# Create application domain and load assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, assemblies, appdomain, .net-assembly

I want to create an application domain with default permissions and load assembly into the application domain with default privileges and execute the methods inside the assembly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173139.aspx) on MSDN. Or if you want to construct an instance of some type inside another AppDomain (assuming this type has a default constructor):

```
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewAppDomain");
var path = @"C:\work\SomeAssembly.dll";
var t = typeof(SomeType);
var instance = (SomeType)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(path, t.FullName);
```

The `instance` variable returned with this method lives on your newly created application domain and you are ready to manipulate it.

Comment: The link you referenced is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps

[Can I reload an assembly in Mono CSharpRepl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585087/can-i-reload-an-assembly-in-mono-csharprepl/5588699#5588699)

```
var dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("tmp");
dom.Load("System.Core");
AppDomain.Unload(dom);
```

See also

[Using multiple versions of the same DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916855/using-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dll/5916866#5916866)